# PHP to exclude specific tablet devices from mobile site

Tags: php, http, mobile, tablet

I am using a php function that looks like this to check whether or not a user to my site is on a mobile device:

```
function isMobileCheckByAgent()
{
return !!preg_match('/(iPod|iPhone|Android|BlackBerry|SymbianOS|SCH-M\d+|Googlebot-Mobile)/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}
```

Now I have two devices, the Asus Nexus 7 and the Galaxy Tab (tablets) that I want to serve my desktop site instead of mobile since their bigger screens can handle it.

So looking at what those devices return from the HTTP_USER_AGENT I decided to look for the strings:

Nexus 7 and Windows NT 6.1

So I wrote:

```
function isMobileCheckByAgent()
{
 if(!!preg_match('/(Nexus 7|Windows NT 6.1)/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) == true)
 {
 return (false);
 }
 elseif(!!preg_match('/(iPod|iPhone|Android|BlackBerry|SymbianOS|SCH-M\d+|Googlebot-Mobile)/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) == true)
 {
 return (true);
 }
 else
 {
 return(false);
 }
}
```

But admittedly my php skills are lacking and failing me here. The devices I want to switch to the desktop site are still being served the mobile site. Does anyone see where I went wrong or how I could improve this function to return what I want? Are spaces allowed in "preg_match('/(Nexus 7|Windows NT 6.1)/'" ? Whats with the double negative "!!"? I'm only doing it myself because the person who wrote this function originally is doing it.

Comment: preg_match will return 0, 1 or false (on error). the double negative will do nothing more than cast the ints to booleans. so any non-zero value is true and zero is false.

Comment: Don't do this. It's a maintenance nightmare. If you insist on serving different pages, use a library that helps with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.` (dot) is treated as a wildcard character in regular expressions.  It is used to match practically any character.  Escape your `.` with a backslash (`\`) like this: `\.` if you want to use a literal period.  A reference that might help: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

The way you're trying to coerce a boolean from `preg_match()` is poor.  If I'm not mistaken, 0 is false and any other number is true in PHP.  I personally wouldn't rely on that though and would deem it bad style.  `!0` would thus result as true and `!!0` would result as false.  Just test for integer 0, not for truth.

Documentation on `preg_match()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Also, the way `if()` works is that it tests the expression inside the parenthesis.  If that expression evaluates to true, the next statement (whether it's a single statement or a block statement) is run.  There are boolean operators (i.e. `==`, `||`, etc.) that return a boolean value.  For example `$test == 0` will evaluate to either true or false, depending on whether `$test` evaluates to integer 0 or not.

Also, having two `return false;` statements in this function is redundant.  Why not just test for the iPod, iPhone, etc?  If that doesn't `return true;`, then `return false;`.

Comment: I fixed it by using GT-P3113 instead of Windows NT 6.1 for the Tab 2 and using 1 and 0s as return values instead of bools. Great answer as you caught both parts that weren't functioning correctly.